# How to pass method parametrs with $http URL in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

This is my webservice method

```
[WebMethod]
public static string UpdateRec(string ID){
    string s = "";
    s = ID;

    return s;
}
```

then this is my AnjularJS script code

```
$http({
        url: 'Employees.aspx/UpdateRec',
        method: 'post',
        data: '',
        headers:{
            "contenttype": "application/json"
        }
    })
    .success(function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    });
};
```

Comment: Have you tried passing in the data?